# Python -Get the body of an multipart email

Tags: python, email, multipart

i get an email with the following code:

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(MailReceiveSRV)
m.login(MailReceiveUSER, MailReceivePWD)
m.select("Inbox")
status, unreadcount = m.status('INBOX', "(UNSEEN)")
unreadcount = int(unreadcount[0].split()[2].strip(').,]'))
items = m.search(None, "UNSEEN")
items = str(items[1]).strip('[\']').split(' ')
for index, emailid in enumerate(items):
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)
    for part in mail.walk():
        body = part.get_payload()
```

FYI: This is always a part of the examplecode.

But body is now a biiig list of objects. If the Content_Type would be Plaintext, it would be much easier.

How can i get access to the body of that mail now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

You have a multiparted email. That's why you're getting a list instead of a string: `get_payload` returns a list of `Message` if it's a multipart message, and `string` if it's not.

### Explanation

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload):

> Return the current payload, which will be a list of `Message` objects when `is_multipart()` is `True`, or a string when `is_multipart()` is `False`.

Hence `get_payload` returning a list.

Your code for getting the body would be something like:

```
if email_message.is_multipart():
    for part in email_message.get_payload():
        body = part.get_payload()
        # more processing?
else:
    body = email_message.get_payload()
```

Again, [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.is_multipart):

> Note that `is_multipart()` returning `True` does not necessarily mean that "msg.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart'" will return the `True`. For example, `is_multipart` will return `True` when the `Message` is of type *message/rfc822*.

Comment: Maybe instead of just body=part.getpayload() when multipart is true, you could append the body to a growing string. The way it's written, you'll just get the last part and discard all others.